# Receiving Unhandled exception and unreachable catch block in the same line of java code

Tags: java, try-catch, unhandled-exception, validationexception

In the following code I receive 2 errors:

> 1. Unhandled exception type ValidationException at line xxx
> 2. Unreachable catch block for ValidationException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body at line yyy

```
public void validateExistingTemplate() {
  try{
  dummyObject.validate();   //line xxx
  }
  catch(ValidationException e){ // line yyy
      //to do 
  }
}

try {
List emailOptionsList = someHelper.someMethod(SomeClass.class, 
    criterion, null, false);
if(emailOptionsList.size() > 0) {
  operationContext.addErrorMessages(new Message("ERROR_MESSAGE"));
} 
} catch (ServiceApplicationException ex) {
  throw new ValidationException();
}
}
```

I am not sure how to get rid of this. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post a validate method form your dummyObject.

Comment: also, make sure you are catching the correct ValidationException. If you have two Exceptions with the same name, but different packages, this could cause the issue

Comment: You may be importing another ValidationException - check your imports.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem was with the wrong import. After correcting the error is gone. thanks.

Comment: close this question by providing your own answer or delete question